# How do I open a blue chest?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I came across a Blue Chest in the Deep Dark Forest which was magically sealed. I initially thought this meant I needed a key, but I didn't find one anywhere in the forest, which leads me to believe there is a different method for opening magically sealed chests.

How do I open a blue chest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Blue chest can be unlocked by casting the spell **Spring Lock** on them.

> This spell is unlocked after restoring the heart of Ding Dong Dells king.